# Is this construction of the sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, tenses, construction

Today I see ways how several aspects of filmmaking industry can be improved so that myriads of struggling filmmakers won’t be left overboard and can find their niche in this very complex business.

Comment: It would help if you point out the area you suspect to be wrong

Comment: In fact if you don't, this question will be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a missing comma. Otherwise, you're good to go.

> **Today,** I see ways how several aspects of filmmaking industry can be
>   improved so that myriads of struggling filmmakers won’t be left
>   overboard and can find their niche in this very complex business.

Comment: "ways how" is non-standard.  "how" or "ways that " would be more understandable.

Comment: CMOS: Shorter adverbial phrases are less likely to merit a comma than longer ones:
_After 1956 such complaints about poor fidelity became far less common._

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: I looked into that. How can be a relative adverb. You're right, though. `ways that` sounds better.